# Symfony2, Doctrine, update db entry without queryBuilder

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

To save entry to db we can use:

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

But how can we update existing entry without using `$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery()` ?

Can we?

I'm searching some kind of `$em->update()` for existing entry in db.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple way to do, **Fusselchen** said right, just show an example

```
// get entity manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

// get from this entity manager our "entity" \ object in $item
// also we can get arrayCollection and then do all in foreach loop
$item = $em->getRepository('repoName')->findOneBy($filter);

// change "entity" / object values we want to edit
$item->setSome('someText')
//...

// call to flush that entity manager from which we create $item
$em->flush();
// after that in db column 'some' will have value 'someText'

// btw after call flush we can still use $item as 'selected object' in
// another $em calls and it will have actual (some = 'someText') values
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't exist a function like `$em->update()`.
You have to fetch object from DB and update it or, simply, write a custom query (with DQL) that update what you need

As you can see [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries)

```
UPDATE MyProject\Model\User u SET u.password = 'new' WHERE u.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

This is an example of DQL query for updating an entity named User

Last but not least important, this query have to be placed into aspecial "class" called repository that will contain all custom sql (dql).
This is a good practice.

Learn more about repositories, [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Comment: thank you, your answer also useful, but guy above was first.. thnx again

Comment: @user1954544 he isn't the first. I answered 29 minutes ago, and he 18 minutes ago, so mine was the first. But nevermind...

Comment: @user1954544: ps.: best answers have to be accepted, not "most fast"

Comment: "No, it doesn't exist a function like $em->update()." This is wrong, merge operation in dql is meant exactly for updating models that are detached from manager by now. It basically will do the select part for you so merge is the nearest equivalent for update.

Comment: @AlTal I guess you didn't understood neither the question nor the answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the Entity from DB
2. Change the values you want to modify
3. flush the entitymanager

no extra call for updating the database. The EntityManager keeps your model an Database in sync on flush()

```
public function updateAction($id)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $product->setName('New product name!');
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object